# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity dynamic schema mapping issue

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to do a dynamic schema mapping in Azure Data Factory but with little luck.

I am having trouble to cast or convert when sinking. the JSON_Query incapsulates the json as a string and is also escaping the double quotes. I need a clean JSON object to work with.

The Source SQL statement

```
SELECT 
      [table]
      ,JSON_query(data_context) as data_context
      ,[operation]
      ,[updated_at] FROM [BIS_ChangedDataOnEventStage]
where [id] <= 5000
```

the result

```
[
    {
        "table": "pnt",
        "data_context": "{\"pnt_name\":\"P000_KLAUS22\",\"pnt_no\":136,\"}",
        "operation": "DEL",
        "updated_at": "2023-08-17T07:51:42.447"
    }
]
```

What I would like is the following result

```
[{
    "table": "pnt",
    "data_context": {
        "pnt_name": "P000_KLAUS22",
        "pnt_no": 136
    },
    "operation": "DEL",
    "updated_at": "2023-08-17T07:51:42.447"
}]
```

I have been trying al sorts of things with the translator object. My best guess is to explain ADF how to read the object therafter declaring sink properties.

```
{
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "mappings": [
            {
                "source": {
                    "path": "context.$['pnt_name']",
                    "type": "Object"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "path": "pnt_name",
                    "type": "Object"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share sample data from your table?

Comment: "table": "pnt",
        "data_context": "{\"pnt_name\":\"P000_KLAUS22\",\"pnt_no\":136,\"}",
        "operation": "DEL",
        "updated_at": "2023-08-17T07:51:42.447"

Comment: what is the destination? you want to store `pnt_name` in destination?

Comment: I would like the following result:
{
    "table": "pnt",
    "data_context": {
        "pnt_name": "P000_KLAUS22",
        "pnt_no": 136
    },
    "operation": "DEL",
    "updated_at": "2023-08-17T07:51:42.447"
}

Comment: If you select from SQL as datatype is nvarchar it will take it as string and from mapping I can see you want `pnt_name` in sink for that you nedd to use `JSON_VALUE` in query with below query `SELECT [table],JSON_VALUE(data_context,'$.pnt_name') as data_context,[operation],[updated_at] FROM [BIS_ChangedDataOnEventStage]` you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/MsAHUGg.png)

Comment: `JSON_VALUE(column_name,'$.element_from_object')` it wiil helpful for you?

Comment: @PratikLad thanks for your advice. I am using the following SQL statement:
SELECT 
      [table]
      ,JSON_query(data_context) as data_context
      ,[operation]
      ,[updated_at] FROM [BIS_ChangedDataOnEventStage]
where [id] <= 5000

Comment: I need to be very flexible with the content of the json object. Not knowing in advance whats inside

Answer (score 0):

In Azure SQL to store the Json we use column data type as `nvarchar` and in ADF it considers `String` As Data Factory interim data type for `nvarchar` in SQL as per this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?tabs=data-factory#data-type-mapping-for-azure-sql-database)

From the mapping you shared it looks like you want to map the **pnt_name** from the Json in **data_context** column of SQL source.

**To achieve this, you have two ways:**

**1. You need to use `JSON_VALUE` function in the source query itself to get the `pnt_name`` as a single column and the map it with tour destination column.**

- **Sample Query:**

```sql
SELECT [table],JSON_VALUE(data_context,'$.pnt_name') as pnt_name,[operation],[updated_at] FROM [BIS_ChangedDataOnEventStage]
```

- **Preview Data:**
  [image]
- **Mapping:**
  [image]
- **Mapping Json:**

```json
 "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "table",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "nvarchar"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "table",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "String"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "pnt_name",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "nvarchar"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "pnt_name",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "String"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "operation",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "nvarchar"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "operation",
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "String"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "updated_at",
                                    "type": "DateTime",
                                    "physicalType": "datetime"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "updated_at",
                                    "type": "DateTime",
                                    "physicalType": "DateTime"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
```

**2. Use Dataflow to to get the `pnt_name` as a single column and the map it with tour destination column.**

- Add SQL table with source and the query to get the desired column then with the parse transformation parse the jsomn column and get the respective element from it.
  Output column type: `(pnt_name as string,       pnt_no as integer)`
  [image]
- After this with select transformation select the particular columns.
  [image]
- Then Mapp columns with destination and copy it below will be result.
  [image]